# $f:[a, +\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ continuous, positive monotone not increasing, show that if $\int_a^{\infty} f(t) \ dt$ convergent, then $\lim xf(x) = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

I need to show that if

$$\int_a^{\infty}f(t)\ dt$$ convergent, then $$\lim xf(x) = 0$$

where $f$ is positive, monotone not increasing.

I though of doing something with the Riemann sums, like:

$$\sum f(x)(x_{k}-x_{k-1}) = a$$

where $a<\infty$, then trying to relate $\sum x_kf(x)-x_{k+1}f(x)$, as you see, $xf(x)$ appears inside the sum, but I didn't find this effective. Does somebody have an idea?

Answer (score 4):

Observe
\begin{align}
\frac{x}{2}f(x)\leq\int^{x}_{x/2} f(t)\ dt\rightarrow 0
\end{align}
as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: how did you get this identity and how it'll prove? sorry i'm too noob

Comment: Since your function is monotone and non-increasing, then the right endpoint  will be the smallest value on the interval $[x/2, x]$. Also, note the interval has length $x-x/2 = x/2$.